# noun: plural or singular?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, nouns

In this sentence: "Mountains and lakes are typical of the `landscape(s)` in Switzerland." landscape should be used singular or plural? Why?

Comment: Either is fine.  The singular is more common; if plural "Switzerland's landscapes" or "landscapes of Switzerland" are probably more common bit "in Switzerland" is not incorrect.

Comment: _A landscape_ is a particular bit of scenery, or the landscape in a particular local area.

Comment: One landscape can include several mountains and lakes.

Comment: It's a question of how the writer is thinking about it. They might use singular to generalize about the whole country, or they might use plural and go on to characterize individual local landscapes within the country.